# How to adjust the y-axis range in effect_plot function

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot raw outcome values against variable `insulin`, with a regression line on top. I followed the instruction here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jtools/vignettes/effect_plot.html but I have a question about adjusting y-axis.

Do you know how may I customize my y-axis scales? For example, how can I set y-axis scale ranged from -10 to 0, with -2 increment? Sorry for this silly question, I'm new to R and most code I googled did not seem to work with the `effect_plot()` function. Below is my code:

```
pct_fat <- lm(pct_fat_change ~ DXA_age + female + race + hispanic + insulin, data = example)


effect_plot(example, pred = insulin, interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE, colors = "red")
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: HI! Welcome to SO! Please consider to format your code as actual code using `{}` icon in the edit section , or by using "`" (backquote)  tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a toy example to change the y_axis limits.

effect_plot returns a ggplot object, so assign it to a variable.

```
library(ggplot2)
require(jtools)

data(mpg)

fit <- lm(cty ~ displ + year + cyl + class + fl, data = mpg[mpg$fl != "c",])

g <- effect_plot(fit, pred = displ, interval = TRUE, plot.points = TRUE, colors = "red")
```

After that, you can work on it as a ggplot object, here below 2 distinct way to achieve your result. (Suppose you want to rescale the y_axis from 20 to 32)

```
g +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(20, 32))

g+
  ylim(20, 32)
```